# Как получить имя исполняемого файла по идентификатору процесса

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Нужно получить полное имя исполняемого файла (exe) зная идентификатор процесса.

Основываясь на утверждении, что сам экзешник является первым (главным) модулем приложения, написал такой код:

```
HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pid);
MODULEENTRY32 meModuleEntry;
meModuleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
Module32First(hSnapshot, &meModuleEntry);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hSnapshot)
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("ERROR"), _T("Information"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
else
    MessageBox(NULL, meModuleEntry.szExePath, _T("Information"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Таким образом, если в `pid` передавать идентификатор своего процесса, то все работает. Но если передать любой другой идентификатор (например explorer'a), то переменная `hSnapshot` принимает значение `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Что я делаю не так? Или таким образом нельзя просмотреть модули чужого процесса?

Comment: Решено! Проблема оказалась в том, что я компилировал приложение под x86, а запускал на 64-битной системе. WOW64 позволяет запускать 32-битные приложения, но в этом случае для 64-битных процессов `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pid)` возвращает `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, а для 32-битных работает нормально.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [виде ответа к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено! Проблема оказалась в том, что я компилировал приложение под x86, а запускал на 64-битной системе. WOW64 позволяет запускать 32-битные приложения, но в этом случае для 64-битных процессов `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pid)` возвращает `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, а для 32-битных работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем такие сложности. Вот так проще:

```
auto proccess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
if(NULL == process)
{
    auto error = GetLastError();
    // ругаемся
}
else
{
   TCHAR * image_path        = nullptr;
   DWORD   image_path_lenght = 0;
   if(!QueryFullProcessImageName(   process
                                 ,  0
                                 , &image_path
                                 , &image_path_lenght ))
   {
       // опять ругаемся
   }
   else
   {
      // готово
   }

   CloseHandle(process);
   process = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Интересная функция QueryFullProcessImageName, жаль только с Висты поддерживается...

Comment: Дело в том, что не каждый процесс даст себя открыть через OpenProcess

Comment: Опять же для процессов ОС данный код не срабатывает (например для explorer.exe или notepad.exe)